# How to pass an Auto variable as input to another function

Tags: c++, auto

I really want to pass a variable that is `auto` (function) as input in another function.

Here is a structure that receives parameters for my `xroot f`:

```cpp
struct my_f_params { 
    double flag; 
    auto inter_auto(double x, double y);
};
```

Here is the function I essentially want to have (it's based on a GSL library, so the form can't be changed). I want to be able to pass a "function" as a variable, and the only way I guessed it would happen is with `auto`.

After passing it, I try storing it to a new `auto`, But I get an error (see below):

```cpp
double xrootf (double x, void * p)
{
    my_f_params * params = (my_f_params *)p;
    double flag = (params->flag);
    auto inter_auto = (params->inter_auto);    
    return flag*inter_auto(x);
}
```

Here is an `auto` function that returns an `auto` function. This works perfectly (if `xrootf` is commented, I can print for example `new_f(2)(2)`, etc):

```cpp
auto new_f(double x){
    auto in_result = [](double x, double y){
        return x*y;
    };

    using namespace std::placeholders;
    auto result_f = std::bind(in_result,x,_1);
    
    return result_f;
}
```

The test code that proves that the `auto` function `new_f` is working good:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    auto nest_f = new_f(-0.5);
    printf("%f\n", nest_f(+2));
    return 0;
}
```

Recasting the `auto` function to `double` is not working, either (for the struct part of the code).

The error I'm getting is:

```
auto_pass.cpp: In function 'double xrootf(double, void*)':
auto_pass.cpp:28:42: error: unable to deduce 'auto' from 'params->my_f_params::inter_auto'
28 |     auto inter_auto = (params->inter_auto);
   |                                          ^
auto_pass.cpp:28:42: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'auto'
```

The aim of the code is this:

1. Have a function that is able to return a function (DONE W/ new_f)
2. Have a function that is able to take a function as a variable (the one with new_f) (Not Done)

**EDIT**: Here's a quick Python script that's very easy to achieve what I'm saying:

```py
def new_f(y):
    #make any number of computatioanly costly Algebra with y
    def g(x):
        return x*y
    return g
def xroot(f,flag):
    return flag-f(flag)
```

Comment: This looks more C-- than C++.

Comment: function 'inter_auto' with deduced return type cannot be used before it is defined.

Comment: `auto` is just a placehold for the actual type infered from the initializer, there arent variables of type `auto`.

Comment: @Enlico Ok sorry, It's my 4th day on Cpp and I'm a more into Physics. No need to be sarcastic

Comment: @BillyMatlock, to be less sarcastic, the way you crafted the question is not conformant to [_how-to-ask_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For instance, you've technically just thrown a code on the page, with your explanation being merely _pass a variable that is Auto (Function) as input in another function_ which is insufficient and incorrect.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Yeah but for example I can call `nest_f(2)` and it will print it correctly. Even though I know it's double, I can't recast `nest_f` as a double as to pass it to my function `xroot_f`

Comment: i dont understand what the code is supposed to do either. Do you not have a definition for hte method `inter_auto` ? What is the line `auto inter_auto = (params->inter_auto);` supposed to mean?

Comment: @Enlico You are right. I'm sorry. I tried to explain evrything I write with last edit. Also this is not the part of code I used, so I tried to make a MWE just to post it here, for it to be clear enough. So its not that I didnt try to post the question as clear as I could

Comment: can you try to explain what you are trying to do without using the word auto? Its kinda confusing because I don't understand what you mean with "auto function". Is it possible that you want `my_f_params` to be a structure that holds two member variables that you can pass to some other function? It isnt. Its a structure with one member variable and one member fucntion that you declared but did not define. There is no way to deduce the return type of `auto inter_auto(double x, double y);` without its definition

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 You are right. Really sorry. Edited the question. Didnt want to be vague.

The aim of the code is this:

1) Have a function that is able to return a function (DONE W/ new_f)

2) Have a function that is able to take a function as a variable (the one with new_f) (Not Done)

`auto inter_auto = (params->inter_auto); ` is an `auto` variable to append the `params->inter_auto` function as the input of `xrootf` suggests

Comment: what is `params->inter_auto` ? You declared it but you didnt define the method

Comment: `new_f` can be written as `auto new_f(double x){ return [x](double y) { return x*y;}; }`. You do not need `bind` here. If you want to return a callable that takes a single parameter then just return a callable that takes a single parameter instead of first creating one with two parameters and then binding one of them. The capture of the lambda is the much easier alternative comared to `bind`.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Ok, sorry again. I wrote on the Question what I want to achieve with this MWE.  And thank you for your time, honestly.


I want to have a `function` that gets  the result of `new_f` as a variable. <-. THe part of the code  `params->inter_auto`  is confusing but I just want to pass `inter_auto` variable (that came from new_f) to the function namespace as a new "`variabe`"

Comment: `my_f_params::inter_auto` is not a member variable, it is a member function (without definition).

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 You said "just return a callable that takes a single parameter instead of first creating one with two parameters and then binding one of them." 

Thats basically a function right? I mean it gets one parameter, I thought the only way of doing that is through auto and bind

Comment: still not sure, but I still believe that you think you can store some parameters in `my_f_params`, a `double` and a function, but you cant

Comment: I say "callable" because a lambda is not a function. Its a function object

Comment: Do you want `my_f_params` to be a structure that holds a `double` and a custom function so that you can pass them to `xrootf` and use that double and the custom function inside `xrootf` ?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Yes thats what I try to do. But the function is created through the `auto` command.  So I dont know if I should call it a function or what. But you got my point. 

** Also** maybe check the last last part of the Question. Thats EXACTLY what I try to achieve but on Cpp (in order to be faster).

Comment: "But the function is created through the auto command" you seem to have some misconception concerning `auto`. `auto` does not mean "any type"! It means "the compiler can figure out the type and replace it for me right there". The compiler still needs a way to deduce the type, but it cannot for `auto inter_auto(double x, double y);`. Anyhow, while I was falling back to old bad habits of discussing in comment someone wrote a great answer that I think covers what you want to do.

Comment: @BillyMatlock in your Python script, `xroot()` is *subtracting* the result of `f(flag)` from the value of `flag`, but in your C++ code, `xrootf()` is *multiplying* the result of `inter_auto(x)` with the value of `flag`. Those are not the same algorithm. So which one do you really want?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Doesn't really matter. I mean the "addition / substraction" is irrelevant. I just want to have a way to pass those function. If I can do multiplication i can do subtraction too. A  pro dude below solved it btw. SO i need to check how it works. Ty all

Comment: @BillyMatlock that "pro dude" was me :)

Comment: OH! TRU. Thanks again <3 Also ty @largest_prime_is_463035818 for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`auto` is just a placeholder for a compiler-deduced type, depending on the context in which `auto` is used.

In your example, you can't use `auto` as the return value of `my_f_params::inter_auto()`, because the compiler has no way to know what type `inter_auto()` actually returns, so it can't deduce the type of the `auto`.  You would need to do this instead:

```cpp
struct my_f_params { 
    double flag; 
    auto inter_auto(double x, double y) { return ...; }
};
```

Then the compiler can deduce the type of the `auto` from the `return` statement.

Without that inline code, you would have to be explicit about the return type, eg:

```cpp
struct my_f_params { 
    double flag; 
    double inter_auto(double x, double y);
};

double my_f_params::inter_auto(double x, double y) {
    return ...;
}
```

But in any case, this is not what you really want.  Your `xrootf()` function is trying to call `inter_auto()` with only one parameter, but `my_f_params::inter_auto()` is declared to take 2 parameters instead.  Based on the Python script you showed, what you really want is for `inter_auto` to be a reference to some other external function instead.  In which case, you can use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) for that purpose (and there is no need to use `std::bind()` with a lambda at all).

Try this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct my_f_params { 
    double flag; 
    std::function<double(double)> inter_auto;
};

double xrootf(double x, void * p)
{
    my_f_params * params = static_cast<my_f_params*>(p);
    return params->flag * params->inter_auto(x);
}

auto new_f(double x){
    return [x](double y) {
        return x * y;
    };
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    my_f_params p;
    p.flag = 123.45;
    p.inter_auto = new_f(-0.5);
    std::cout << xrootf(+2, &p) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/zkuIVT)

When calling `xrootf()`, the resulting equation will be:

`flag * (x * y)`

which in this example is:

`123.45 * (-0.5 * +2) = -123.45`

Comment: WOW. You did it! I didn't even know the existance of `std::function<double(double)>` Give me a moment to think about it

Comment: @BillyMatlock worth mentioning that there is no need for `void*` unless thats a requirement. I suppose it is only in this answer to be in sync with the code in your question. Using `void*` comes with some issues that are better avoided

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Unfortunately, void * has to be the case for the Library I plan to use on the real code (thats thw ""MWE"", its a GSL library for rootfinding)

Comment: @BillyMatlock except that you did not actually provide any MWE showing how `xrootf()` was being used with that library. But that is OK, we get the gist of what you want, no need to go any further.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It worked on me too! Sorry it took some time, Had to add "-lstdc++" for it to be compiled. 

All this was due to `std::function<double(double)>`  ? How did you know exactly it was that? Because I tried casting the lambda/auto or whatever-is-called variable as double but couldnt get it. How did you know you should do it this way?  

Ty again!

Comment: @BillyMatlock "*How did you know you should do it this way?*" - with experience comes wisdom. You'll get there someday, just keep practicing and learning. Get yourself some [good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/).

Comment: Alrighty , just seemed strange to me that you knew you should convert the type to std::function<..> ! Good Job! I have been spending free time on this ( https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-3rd-MIT-Press/dp/0262033844 ) since I'm working on physics.  But will probably change it to a Cpp book :) TY for all